# Google OAuth consent form won't let me submit for verification

Tags: google-oauth

I have a project in Google Cloud Platform that uses OAuth 2.0 and a few scopes from Google. All was working well until recently when I noticed my users were seeing "App is not verified" when logging in with Google.

Visiting the OAuth consent form at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent, I could see that it wanted me to enter new privacy and terms & conditions URLs, which I did. But clicking on Submit For Verification and going through the subsequent popup resulted in no feedback.

Looking in devtools, I could see that the call to the submitReview endpoint was resulting in this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

The request body sent by the Google form was:

{"brandId":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX","scopeRationale":"My rationale was here","additionalInfo":"","contactEmail":"email@domain.com","pendingScopes":[]}

Note that pendingScopes was actually empty (I'm not requesting any new scopes).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've never been to the new OAuth consent screen configuration before, you need to add all the scopes your app is requesting: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en#userconsent